# Is it possible to create an MSI file from a Windows 8.1 Store Application?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, wix, windows-store-apps, windows-installer

I am trying to create an MSI file format from a Windows 8.1 store application in visual studio instead of the standard APPX file format it usually creates using the create app packages function in visual studio.

I have tried using the visual studio installer project but when the MSI file is created. I have tried to use the file to install the application then when I try to run the file it does not run.

There is no documentation on this. So is it possible to do so and if so how can I do this?

Comment: [you've asked the same a few day ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47693791/1466046) store apps have the new appx format and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches you can take in this case:

1. Figure out what dependencies your app requires and include them in the setup.
2. Put enough debugging in your program to tell you what's failing. If the first code you run is (fort example) a messagebox and it never shows then you know your code isn't being loaded, probably because of a missing dependency.

Your question is currently to general to be specific about an answer.